# Subset all data each of which have a following different number

Tags: r

Suppose a vector in the simplest case:

```
value = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)

position = c(1:length(value))

data = cbind(value, position)
```

How can I directly subset those values marked in quotes shown below ?

```
value = c(0,0,0,'0',1,1,1,1,1,'1',2,2,2,2,2,2,'2',1,1,1,1,'1',0,0,0,0,0)
```

Certainly, as well as their position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)

position = c(1:length(value))

data = cbind(value, position)

library(dplyr)

data.frame(data) %>% filter(value != lead(value))

#   value position
# 1     0        4
# 2     1       10
# 3     2       17
# 4     1       22
```

The philosophy is to `filter` (i.e. keep) the rows where `value` is different the the `value` in the next row.

Answer (score 3):

`rle` will give you the `lengths` and the `values` of consecutive runs of same elements in a vector.

```
rle(value)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:5] 4 6 7 5 5
#  values : num [1:5] 0 1 2 1 0
```

Then you can manipulate either the `lengths` or the `values` as per your need.

```
data[head(cumsum(rle(value)$lengths), -1),]
#     value position
#[1,]     0        4
#[2,]     1       10
#[3,]     2       17
#[4,]     1       22
```

Answer (score 2):

You can index based on the differences between consecutive values.

```
i <- c(diff(data[, 'value']) != 0, FALSE)
data[i, ]
#     value position
#[1,]     0        4
#[2,]     1       10
#[3,]     2       17
#[4,]     1       22
```

This can become a one-liner, but I have left it like this to make more clear.